# Why Serenity Update button is Not working

Tags: serenity-platform

While I am updating the details in dialogue window. updated data is not updating in backend.

[dialogue window data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjgMO.png)

[updated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghXC1.png)

explained theoretically.

when I am clicking update button in dialogue window. it triggering the Update Action Button in the ServiceEndpoint Controller. in the request parameter getting updated fields data and executing successfully but data is not updating in the backend.

Please provide the solutions where i am missed logic.

Answer (score 0):

Services and repositories are checks permissions on row, also rows need to have be valid type of property what match the db table column.

If you implement custom logic on your repository, check your implementation for code what prevent to save data.

Check your permissions, editor type and data type on your row.cs form.cs.
Check your chrome developer console for errors
Ensure you try to update table's column, not foreign column. (if you want to update foreign columns in same dialog, you need to implement it manual on save handler)
Monitor your sql query which exec updates on database and try to run it with SSMS or any other sql management tool.